# Using PowerShell to edit 500+ similar text files

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have over 500 text files that have columns of latitude, longitude, and a value. Each file is named based on year and month (So February 2015 is 201502_stag.txt, March 1983 is 198303_stag.txt, etc) but this information is not contained within the file itself. The data just look like this:

```
-140.00   55.00   2
-140.00   54.75   7 
-140.00   54.50   3
```

I want to do three things that I don't know how to do because I am so new to using PowerShell:

1.) Make the title of each file into a repeating column inside the file (so that the years and months won't get mixed up)

2.) Delete all entries in the file with lat and long outside of my area of interest (bounded by a min and max for lat and long each), and

3.) Append all of these files together

I have been using a tutorial to try to figure this out, and I figured out #3 on my own just now. I am scratching my head on the rest and would really like to learn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is something that would also do the trick. To try and take a different approach I changed the output to be of CSV format. If you don't need that it would be easy to change it.

```powershell
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\path\*stag.txt"
$files | ForEach-Object{
    $filedate = ($_.BaseName).Split("_")[0]
    Get-Content $_ | ForEach-Object{
        $line = $_ -split "\s+"
        New-Object -TypeName PsCustomObject  -Property @{
            Date = $filedate
            Lat = $line[0]
            Long = $line[1]
            Index = $line[2]
        }
    }
} | Where-Object{[double]$_.Lat -lt -150 -and [double]$_.Long -lt 54.75} | 
    Select-Object Date,Lat,Long,Index | 
    Export-CSV C:\temp\outputfile.csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
```

This will take all the files in one directory that end with "stag.txt". Take all of there contents and convert it to a PowerShell object with the properties of Date, Lat, Long and Index. I don't know what the last value is so I call it index. The date comes from the portion of the file name before the "_".

Then since we have it as a custom object we can use `Where-Object` and the properties we defined earlier. We cast the values to `[double]` to be use we are using numeric comparison as supposed to alphanumeric. Pipe that into `Select-Object` to get the proper order and export to a tab delimited CSV.

I am assuming you have PowerShell 1 or 2. This would be more terse if you had at least 3 but I am assuming based on your experience.

For testing I made 2 files with the following content

```powershell
#198303_stag.txt
-140.00   55.00   2
-150.00   54.75   7 
-160.00   54.50   3 
#201502_stag.txt
-140.00   58.00   2
-140.00   54.75   7 
-140.00   59.50   3
```

The output from the above code was

```powershell
"Date"  "Lat"   "Long"  "Index"
"198303"    "-160.00"   "54.50" "3"
```

**Output Criticism**

If you don't like what was done here it is no big stretch to make some changes. Just let me know what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Matt, your explanation of the commands is really clear and I am able to follow where I would change things like the min and max values. However when I run this (either interactively) or as a script it just runs and run and never returns anything even after 30 minutes. The output csv is blank. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @HFBrowning How many lines could these files have? Better question would be what is the average size. Reduce the directory to only have a couple of files for testing. What happens with a few test files. Do the productions files really look like your example

Comment: 20 million lines in total :) I checked before I decided I needed to use PS to help me! I'll try on a test subset, great idea

Comment: 20 million <expletive deleted> lines! Ok we can deal with that. Need to update the code to make it more efficient. Continue testing sample files in the mean time to be sure the overall logic is correct.

Comment: Okay I tried it on exactly what you did (new sample files with three lines each, and changed the path of course) and even though it finished really quickly, it still returned a blank output file.

Comment: @HFBrowning I will double check the initial logic then to be sure that part is at least working. Be back to you in 30 minutes

Comment: @HFBrowning Check the Where-Object. I updated the post since my code didnt match my output (must have missed an edit. ). Had to change `[double]$_.Lat -gt -150` to `[double]$_.Lat -lt -150`. The math was wrong. Use my files for testing and remove the whole where-object if you would like just to see all file data.

Comment: Hi Matt, accepting and upvoting for your incredible help. The file keeps spitting out blanks for one of the columns on the real files but I think it might have something to do with spacing. I'm close enough now to be able to tweak. I learned a lot, thanks!!

Comment: @HFBrowning if you do get stuck you can let me know or make a new question and reference this one. Which column? Does the source file look _exactly_ like the same you have above?

Comment: I wrote back too quickly - I just got it to work completely on 2 of the 500 files. The change I needed to make was just starting the variable assignment at line[1] instead of line[0] for some reason. It was pretty quick too so I think doing all 500 should be reasonable :)

Comment: @HFBrowning guessing your real files have leading whitespace in front of the first value then. Good catch. Happy PowerShelling

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you can do this with a one-liner.

```js
gci *stag.txt | %{ $f = $_; gc $f | %{ $l=$_ -split '\s+'; if ([float]$l[0] -eq -140.00 -and [float]$l[1] -ge 50) { $_ + '  ' + $f.Name | ac 'merged.txt' } } }
```

Let's break it down.

```js
<#
    gci is an alias for Get-ChildItem.
    % is an alias for For-Each.
    So, for each file in the current dir matching *stag.txt...
#>
gci *stag.txt | %{

    # Set $f to the current file object.
    $f = $_;

    # Get-Content of the file object.  For each line...
    gc $f | %{

        # $l = the line split on one or more spaces.
        $l = $_ -split '\s+';

        <#
            If...
                * the first word equals -140, and
                * the second word is greater than or equal to 50
            Then...
        #>
        if ([float]$l[0] -eq -140.00 -and [float]$l[1] -ge 50) {

            <#
                Append-Content to merged.txt
                * The unmodified line
                * Literal two spaces
                * The name of the file
            #>
            $_ + '  ' + $f.Name | ac 'merged.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

While this solution doesn't actually delete any lines from the original files, the irrelevant lines are excluded from merged.txt.

Comment: It should be noted that `$l[0] -eq -140.00 -and $l[1] -ge 50` would be a string operations and not an arithmetic operation.

Comment: Ah, right.  I should've cast them as `[float]`.  Nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Powershell v3 or later ($PSVersiontable), then try this:

```
    # specify path to files
    $path = "path\to\files"

    # thresholds. casting to [double] to use arithmetic operations on them
    $latmin = [double]-150
    $latmax = [double]-120
    $longmin = [double]54.75
    $longmax = [double]60

    # array for output. cache all results here before export to file, this will minimize IO operations and save some time
    $out = @()

    # read file by file
    foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter "*_stag.txt") 
    {
        # display some progress information
        echo "Proceeding file $file"
        $filename = $file.BaseName.Replace('_stag','') # or just $file.BaseName
        # read contents
        $contents = (Get-Content $file.FullName)
        # proceed every line, splitting by whitespace (one or more)
        # if field delimiter is tab character, replace splitter with '\t+'
        # for each line we construct an object and add it to output array
        $contents | foreach { $tokens = $_ -split '\s+'; $out += [pscustomobject]@{Date = $filename; Lat = [double]$tokens[0]; Long = [double]$tokens[1]; Num = [int]$tokens[2]}  }
    }
    $out | ft
    # exclude unnecessary entries and export to file
    $out | where { ($_.Lat -ge $latmin) -and ($_.Lat -le $latmax) -and ($_.Long -ge $longmin) -and ($_.Long -le $longmax) } | Out-File -Encoding utf8 "$path\out.txt"
```

Just specify your path to files and criteria.

EDITED:

Cast to [double] instead of [int]. Thanks to Matt.

Comment: You shouldn't cast the numbers to `int` as you will lose the decimal.